# Strange chevrons in tabled data in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel-5.5

I am seeing chevrons in my tables to the right of the data before the border.

The css has no images or nothing out of the ordinary either, could it be a javascript issue, jquery or something?
I am not sure what to post here, Here is a sample of the html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>xxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th>xxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th>xxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th>xxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th>xxxxxxxx</th>
                <th>xxxxxx</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
                        <tr class="gradeX">
                <td>xxxxxxxx</td>
                <td>xxxxxx</td>
                <td>xxxxxxxxx</td>
                <td>xxxxxxxx</td>
                <td>xxxxxxxx</td>

                <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
            </tr>
```

[image: strange chevrons in IE and Edge]

Thanks in advance, not sure what else to post, please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard for me to know specifically what the issue looks like with these fixes because I dont have IE but from the experience I have had with IE these few things might fix the issue...

1) It could be that you haven't specified a DOCTYPE.

Without a doctype, IE will start all kinds of rendering glitches. To fix this problem, simply add a valid doctype to the top of the page, before the `<html>` tag.

If you're not sure which doctype to use, use the HTML5 doctype - it's as simple as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

2) It could also possibly be overflow issue. If there is too much data in a cell IE might try to add the scrollbar so try:

```
table {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

3) If it is an overflow issue and the above didnt work, it can be common that tables exceed the width they are given so this can fix that:

```
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Documentation on this is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> set, I also tried the two css table options, still nothing. What would you like to see, I can share more, but it is a large laravel project, using a pretty standard bootstrap template.

Comment: Scratch my last, I was updating the wrong template css file, (facepalm). One for front end and another for administration. Thanks for the help

Comment: @The-WebGuy haha no worries buddy! It happens :) Glad you fixed it though. always happy to help!